# force to use join in nhibernate syntax instead of iteration

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate

i am trying to figure out why nhibernate query iterates on values instead of using joins internally. due to this iteration it becomes slower, cause it will iterates all values one by one.
i.e. it generates n no. of queries and execute it one by one instead of joins.

`documentClrType` is evaluated dynamically at runtime, so i can't use directly in `QueryOver<>` syntax

`documentClrType` is FactSheetPrivate as of now.

i observed query in logger it is created something like this.

- `select * from foo where col1=@val1`
- `select * from foo where col1=@val2`
- `select * from foo where col1=@val3`
- `select * from foo where col1=@val4`

so,

- how could i turn this query to joins instead of iterations?
- what could be syntax for this dynamic types with query over?

i am bit new to nhibernate, any guidance will be appreciated.

```
var criteria=
store.Session.
CreateCriteria(documentClrType)
.Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
.Add(Restrictions.Le("CreationDate",)DateTime.Now )
.Add(Restrictions.Le("AccurateDate",)DateTime.Now )
)

criteria=criteria.CreateCriteria("Entity")
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("DBTypeString",receiverType))

return criteria.List<IDocument>()
// at this lines instead of join query iterates value one by one
```

following screen display entity nhibernate xml file
[image: entity nhibernate xml file]

following screen display packets nhibernate XML file

[image: Packet.xml file]

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has a feature to batch the selects

```
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.DefaultBatchFetchSize, "20")
```

or use eager fetching

```
return criteria.SetFetchMode("TheReferenceOrCollectionProperty", FetchMode.Eager).List<IDocument>()
```